# Using GDAL to Create Dataset?

Tags: gdal, c#, geotiff-tiff

Treat me as a beginner.

I have this method, where the bandArray is the original image `double[]` array

```
private double[] ApplyAverageSmoothingNxN(double[] bandArray, int width, int height, int n)
{
    //logic inside here (not relevant)
}
```

This method returns me a `double[]` array which is actually the raster file. After the methods returns I try to save the output using Gdal like so:

```
composedDs = drv.Create(path + "smoothed.tif", XSize, YSize, 1, DataType.GDT_Int16, null);
composedDs.SetGeoTransform(transform);
composedDs.WriteRaster(0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize, result, band.XSize, band.YSize, 1, null, 0, 0, 0);
composedDs.Dispose();
```

Now, after I open the output tif image, I see everything black (all 0's). But if I try to run my code again, the raster has all it's values correct. However, if I try to assign all values of the output `double[]` array like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
     array[i] = 10 //some value.. could be anything else
}
```

After I save it with `Gdal.Create()` Arcmap displays pixel values correctly. What is happening ?

Also my input image is a ".jp2" file while the output is done with "GTiff" driver as ".tif".

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue! The problem was that I had to assign `pixelSpace` parameter and `lineSpace` parameter to 1 and 1 respectively. These are practically pixel dimensions.

Here is what I have modified:

```
composedDs.WriteRaster(0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize, result, band.XSize, band.YSize, 1, null, 1, 1, 1);
```