# GDAL WriteRaster as single band GeoTiff using C# saves as all black image

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c#

I am new to the community. I am fairly new to GDAL, and I'm using the C# library. I have a single band raster for which I ran multiple analyses on, and for each, I saved them using GDAL WriteRaster - no issues with that or the code for those methods (that I know of yet).

Then I realized I need to actually create one more raster, for which two single cells are both assigned any value aside from the default zero value - ***but the value of these two cells need to be the same***. You can imagine these as an origin and destination cell in the raster. All other values should be zero or NoData (or any other value as long as they're all the same).

So I am using almost exactly the same code as my previous methods, and I've omitted all the unnecessary math from the previous methods. So then I just assign a value in my cell array for the origin and for the destination cell. I write the entire cell array to the new raster and then I view the results in ArcMap. Everything comes out black. It should be all black with the exception of two cells that are white. When I'm debugging, I know that the array has the correct values at the origin and destination cell indices, but something is happening when writing raster that doesn't appear correct in ArcMap. Interestingly, when I read in the newly created raster (the one that looks all black), and I perform some math on that raster, I actually get results that show the origin and destination cells have the correct values. Even more interesting, is that if I assigned the origin cell a value of 10, and the destination cell a value of 11, and all other cells zero, the raster actually comes out black with two cells looking white. However, I need the values to be the same.

It seems so simple, yet it has puzzled me for hours! I found a [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283420/using-gdal-to-create-dataset) that had a similar issue using GDAL. However, I tried assigning pixelspace and linespace to values of 1, and that didn't work either. I also saw some recommendations about flushing cache and disposing of the data set, but that also didn't change anything.

Below is a sample of my code. I've omitted some code for handling of multiple bands and all that kind of jazz.

```
// Initialize GDAL
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
OSGeo.GDAL.Driver srcDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
Gdal.AllRegister();
Ogr.RegisterAll();

// Get the GeoTiff file
Dataset srcDS = Gdal.Open(inputRasterPath, Access.GA_ReadOnly);

// Raster size and properties
int width = srcDS.RasterXSize;
int height = srcDS.RasterYSize;
int size = width * height;
double[] gT = new double[6]; // Initialize array to carry the six geotransform coefficients
srcDS.GetGeoTransform(gT); // Get the six geotransform values
double upperLeftX = gT[0]; // Upper left corner's x-position
double upperLeftY = gT[3]; // Upper left corner's y-position
double xStep = gT[1]; // Width of one raster cell
double yStep = gT[5]; // Height of one raster cell

// Let's get the data type of the source raster's bands
Band srcBand = srcDS.GetRasterBand(1);
OSGeo.GDAL.DataType srcDataType = srcBand.DataType;

// Now lets copy the source data set and configure the new raster
string[] options = null;
string wktProj = srcDS.GetProjection();
Dataset ds = srcDriver.CreateCopy(outputRasterPath, srcDS, 0, options, null, null); // This method has worked reliably for me
//Dataset ds = srcDriver.Create(outputRasterPath, width, height, 1, DataType.GDT_Float32, options); 
// The create method had given me issues in my other algorithms. I also tried it for this algorithm and it didn't make a difference

// Dispose of the source
srcBand.Dispose(); // I tried this, it didn't make a difference. I'm not sure if it's safe to do it, but it hasn't thrown me any exceptions
srcDS.Dispose(); // Same consideration as above

// Set the map projection to the same projection as the existing GeoTIFF
ds.SetProjection(wktProj); // Probably not necessary unless I'm using the sourceDrive.Create method

// Set the geotransform to the same as the existing GeoTIFF
ds.SetGeoTransform(gT); // Probably not necessary unless I'm using the sourceDrive.Create method

// Get the raster band(s)
Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1); // All of the rasters I'm currently dealing with are single band rasters

// Create a C# Bitmap instance to store the raster image in
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

// Read the image directly into the C# Bitmap instance using the GDAL read methods
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb); // I actually don't need to read the raster into bmpData since I'm writing all zeros and a couple "ones"

try
{
    // Initialize an empty array that will be used to store the new values to be written to the new raster file
    double[] newValues = new double[size];

    // Get all pixels in the image and assign a value if it's a start or end point
    //for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    //{
    //    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
    //    {
    //        if (row == start.RasterRowIndex && col == start.RasterColIndex)
    //        {
    //            //newValues[col + row * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row) * width] = 1;
    //        }
    //        if (row == end.RasterRowIndex && col == end.RasterColIndex)
    //        {
    //            //newValues[col + row * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col) + (row - 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col) + (row + 1) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col + 1) + (row) * width] = 1;
    //            //newValues[(col - 1) + (row) * width] = 1;
    //        }
    //    }
    //} // This is not necessary. I just wrote this code to see if the issue was with a single cell, as opposed to perhaps 9 cells for each start and end point. It didn't matter, the image came out all black. 


    newValues[start.RasterColIndex + start.RasterRowIndex * width] = -size; // I give it the value as negative size (i.e. width * height). The reason it's negative and that value is beyond the scope of this. But if I gave it any other value, I would still have the same issue.
    newValues[end.RasterColIndex + end.RasterRowIndex * width] = - size; // See comment above

    // Write the new cell values to the raster
    band.WriteRaster(0, 0, width, height, newValues, width, height, 0, 0); // Another post suggest the last two arguments to be 1,1 - however, that did not work for me. Nor did it work if I used the sourceDriver.Create method instead of sourceDriver.CreateCopy method.
    band.FlushCache(); // I added this based on some posts I had seen online, but it also didn't make a difference.
    band.Dispose(); // Added to check if it would make a difference, but it didnt'.
    ds.FlushCache(); // Added to check if it would make a difference, but it didnt'.
    ds.Dispose(); // Added to check if it would make a difference, but it didnt'.

}
finally
{
    // Unlock the bitmap data
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
// Now we can dispose of the C# Bitmap instance
bmp.Dispose();
```

I feel like there must be some very simple answer to this that I'm missing. Perhaps its my understanding of the dataType, lineSpace and pixelSpace?

Comment: Is your pixel type (derived from srcBand.DataType) double, the same as your newValues? You might get some funny values if you're writing double to a long raster.

Comment: what values are you actually using? - does it work if you use a small raster (10x10) and write to ASCII Grid (so you can inspect the values in an editor)? can you add the gdlainfo  output on the output image?

Comment: @MichaelStimson the srcBand.DataType is GDT_FLoat32. I actually forgot to mention in the original post that I had originally tried it with newValues as type "float" and had the same issue. In my other methods using GDAL, I had no issues writing the new raster using double for the data type.

Comment: @IanTurton the values I'm using are: 
(1) zeros for all cells (defaults to this when I initialize the newValues array)
(2) negative size (width*height) for the origin and destination cells

My grid is 100x100 right now, I thought it was small enough. I did not write it to an ASCII grid file, but I'm able to view it in debug mode with the correct values. I will what the results look like shortly.

Comment: Ahh sorry I realized I can't upload images yet into the forum!

Comment: One interesting thing that I just realized is that if I assign the origin cell a value of -1, and the destination cell a value of -2, then based on my original post, the output raster should show the cells as white and the rest of the image black. However, that only happens when the origin and destination cells are _**different values and positive values**_. Everything comes out black if the values are the **_same - or different & negative_**... And by the way, this time around I'm creating the output raster with using the float data type again.